# LoadRunner 12.55 failed to connect the target site

Tags: c, loadrunner

i'm recording with VUG and receive this error when click a button to acces to another page.
[image: Error]

**here is my configuration:**

[image: HTTP/HTML level]

[image: Language]

[image: Correlation]

[image: HTTP properties]

If someone know how to solve it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not certain why you posted images of all of the dialogs.  The germain questions are (1) what does the recording log suggest & (2) What happens when you hit continue....?

Comment: @JamesPulley if i hit continue, IExplorer crash.
Thanks James!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go under recording options and set a new connection. 
Any server, all Ports (value 0) and go further with the settings (direct/proxy etc.). If you are not sure which settings you should use just try and edit them as long as the record is empy